# Загадочные проблемы с хостингом - с открытием каталогов

Tags: ftp, tcp-ip, сервер, хостинг

Здравствуйте! Есть проблема с доступом по FTP. Не могу нормально работать ни в активном, ни в пассивном режиме. Постоянно прерывается, приходится заново переподключаться.
Перепробовал много настроек в Filezilla.
Отключил экраны Avast. Брандмауер... все равно проблема осталась, пробовал другой Ftp клиент.
Логи:

В пассивном режиме выдает следующее:

```
Ответ:  227 Entering Passive Mode (213,155,22,72,137,115).
Команда:    MLSD
Ответ:  150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Ответ:  226 Transfer complete
Статус: Список каталогов извлечен
Статус: Получение списка каталогов...
Команда:    CWD .htpasswd
Ответ:  250 CWD command successful
Команда:    PWD
Ответ:  257 "/domains/julia-wang.ru/.htpasswd" is the current directory
Команда:    PASV
Ответ:  227 Entering Passive Mode (213,155,22,72,138,224).
Команда:    MLSD
Ошибка: Превышено время ожидания соединения
Ошибка: Не удалось получить список каталогов
```

В активном выдает:

```
Статус: Соединение установлено
Статус: Получение списка каталогов...
Команда:    PWD
Ответ:  257 "/" is the current directory
Статус: Список каталогов извлечен
Статус: Получение списка каталогов...
Команда:    CWD /domains/realsila.ru
Ответ:  250 CWD command successful
Команда:    TYPE I
Ответ:  200 Type set to I
Команда:    PORT 77,222,98,114,29,180
Ответ:  500 Illegal PORT command
Ошибка: Не удалось получить список каталогов
```

Пишет неправильный порт, но когда проходишь тест, все ок:

```
Соединяюсь с probe.filezilla-project.org
Ответ: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Ответ: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.9.0.6
Ответ: 230 logged on.
Проверка корректного внешнего IP
IP 77.222.98.114 hh-ccc-ji-bbe
Ответ: 200 OK
PREP 7610
Ответ: 200 Using port 7610, data token 1933903417
PORT 77,222,98,114,29,186
Ответ: 200 PORT command successful
LIST
Ответ: 150 opening data connection
```

Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте другой фтп клиент.

Если есть доступ по ssh, попробуйте sftp.

Возможно, у Вас действительно проблемы с каналом, и ковыряние в настройках не очень поможет. Поможет смена провайдера/места проживания.